# Change the color or parent of an li using jquery even after postback

Tags: jquery, css, postback, parent

I have a tree with the below structure:

```
Home
Products
    Product1
    Product2
Item1
Item2
Item3
```

I have a requirement that when Products1 are selected, the color of Products should be say red.  For that I used the below jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(".leftnav li ul li").click(function(){
       var thisAnchor = $(this);
       var parent = $(thisAnchor).parent().parent();
       $(parent).children("a").css('color','red');
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Here leftnav is the class used on the div containing the tree structure.  The color is changed as soon as I click on **Product1**, but goes away as soon as the page postbacks. Can someone guide me how to solve this issue.

Regards,
Swati Jain

Comment: i edited your question, so the sourcecode is more visible.

Comment: Found the solution:  Instead of calling the click function, I did the below:                                                                    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
      
      var parent = $(".leftnav li ul li").parent().parent();     
      $(parent).children("a").css('color','red');
  
  });

     </script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to maintain state across postbacks.  Either you can

1. postback the current selection state to the server and setup the colors on the generated html for the postback
2. store the current selection state in a cookie (look at the jquery cookie plugin) and modify the colors on `document.ready`

Comment: @user1427623 No problem.  Please mark the question as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to either set the class dynamically using php or set a page id/class so the pages know where it is. e.g. if you are on the products page the body tag would have a id or products. Then in you CSS you can set products nav element to be red

```
body#products .leftnav li ul li.on{
 color: red;
}
```

You html would be on the products page something like this:

```
<body id="products">
...
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li class="on">
         Products
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Matpol, this is actually a Sharepoint navigation tree, the css for each li element has to be the same, so I can not use the above solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could probably get the pages url on docoment ready and do some if conditions or you could just add a static jscript on the page that loads changing the color,again on page ready. Btw to grab the url just write var url = window.location.href